# Generic function to handle all objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model built for a "person" which has email addresses.

```
public class Person{
     public string name;
     public List<Email> email;
}

public class Email : Primary {
     public string emailAddress;
}

public class Primary {
     public bool IsPrimary;
}
```

When I'm displaying in Razor I only want to display the email which are set to primary == true.

I wanted to write a function method as I have many many collections which inherit from Primary (addresses, providers etc)

```
<div class="value">
                @getPrimary(Model.Email)
</div>

@functions{
     public T getPrimary <T> (List<T> collection){
          foreach (T thing in collection){
               ??? if (((Primary)thing).primary) ???
          }
     }
}
```

Is there any way to do this....?

What I don't want is a list of tests against all my differing types. I would really like a simple "You inherit from primary therefore I can test for that the return the primary record from the list you passed in". Does that help?

Thanks

======================================== RESOLUTION ====================================

```
public T getPrimary<t>(List<T> collection) where T : HasPrimary
{
    var d = collection.OfType<HasPrimary>().Where(i => i.Primary);
    if (d.Count() == 0)
        return (T)collection.FirstOrDefault();
    return (T)d.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what your question is. Are you looking for constraints on generic type parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`collection.OfType<Primary>()`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx